# Calling python function from C as a callback. What is the right way to handle the GIL?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, gil

I'm using `cytpes` to wrap a C api. One of the api functions allows you to register a callback. I'm using `CFUNCTYPE` to to specify the function's type and make an instance of `CFUNCTYPE` from a python function that the user of my python library provides which I then pass to the C function (called with the `ctypes` api).

I know that `ctypes` calls release the `GIL`. I'm wondering what happens when the C library function calls my python callback function. Does `ctypes` reacquire the `GIL`?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) says:

> **Note:** Make sure you keep references to `CFUNCTYPE()` objects as long as they are used from C code. `ctypes` doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.
>   Also, note that if the callback function is called in a thread created outside of Python’s control (e.g. by the foreign code that calls the callback), `ctypes` creates a new dummy Python thread on every invocation. This behavior is correct for most purposes, but it means that values stored with `threading.local` will not survive across different callbacks, even when those calls are made from the same C thread.

It doesn't say anything about the `GIL`. Does that mean that it's all handled for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`CThunkObject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#l96) referenced in the callback's `_objects` attribute has the `pcl_exec` function pointer that the C library calls. This code calls [`closure_fcn`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l368) with a reference to the thunk, plus the call `args` and a pointer to memory to store the result. The closure function in turn calls [`_CallPythonObject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l201), with the thunk's `restype`, `setfunc`, `callable`, `converters`, and `flags` as parameters. The first thing `_CallPythonObject` does is call [`PyGILState_Ensure`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PyGILState_Ensure) to acquire the GIL. This works even if this is the first time Python has seen the current thread.

In other words, it's all handled for you. Just keep a reference to the callback to keep the thunk referenced.

Comment: The links to the source are a perfect reference. Thanks!